# list/map of key-value pairs backed up by file on disk

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary

I need to make a list of key-value pairs (similar to `std::map<std::string, std::string>`) that is stored on disk, can be accessed by multiple threads at once. keys can be added or removed, values can be changed, keys are unique. Supposedly the whole thing might not fit into memory at once, so updates to the map must be saved to the disk.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I understand how to deal with multithreading issues, but I'm not sure which data structure is suitable for storing data on disk. Pretty much anything I can think of can dramatically change structure and cause massive overwrite of the disk storage, if I approach problem head-on. On other hand, relational databases and windows registry deal with this problem, so there must be a way to approach it.

Is there a data structure that is "made" for such scenario?
Or do I simply use any traditional data structure(trees or skip lists, for example) and make some kind of "memory manager" (disk-backed "heap") that allocates chunks of disk space, loads them into memory on request and unloads them onto disk, when necessary? I can imagine how to write such "disk-based heap", but that solution isn't very elegant, especially when you add multi-threading to the picture.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure that is "made" for your scenario is [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or its variants, like [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree).

Answer (score 1):

Long and short of it: once you write things to disk you are not longer dealing with "data structures" -  you are dealing with "serialization" and "databases."

The C++ STL and its data structures do not really address these issues, but, fortunately,  they have already been addressed thousands of times by thousands of programmers already. Chances are 99.9% that they've already written something that will work well for you.

Based on your description, [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) sounds like it would be a decent, balanced choice for your application.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of sqlite and similar libraries/projects, but I need to write this thing from scratch. So the question is how to do it. I simply need someone to point into the right direction, because solutions I've been able to think of so far aren't very elegant.

Comment: What you are doing *isn't* something that is simple to implement. To have good performance, concurrency, and larger-than-memory datasets, among other things, functioning well and bug-free you may be looking at more time to write your database from scratch than you were initially planning to spend on the project.  If this is homework help, please tag it accordingly, if this isn't there shouldn't be a reason not to use tried-and-true libraries to help.

Comment: @SigTerm Why do you 'need' to write this from scratch?

Comment: @sirbrilliance: Not homework (I wonder if there are people that give out homework like that)

Comment: @Nick Johnson: "Why do you 'need' to write this from scratch?" I was asked to do it this way, it is job-related. I can turn down the request if I want, though. I can probably write that thing anyway (won't be pretty, but it will work), but I asked the question because I thought that maybe I'm missing important piece of information and there's a well-known elegant way to do it.

Comment: @SigTerm You were specifically asked to write it yourself from scratch? That seems like a rather odd request.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: "That seems like a rather odd request." I'm not going to do something like that for free, so this isn't my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do lookups (and insertions, deletions) by key, and not more complex field-based queries, [BDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) may be a better choice for your application.